# How to avoid "space" between each bullets

Tags: spacing

I am getting an empty row after each bullet and I am looking for a way to avoid an empty row between each line, or at least make the height of that space-row smaller. 
Here is what I do:

```
\documentclass [11pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\input std-defs
\input EECE2323-header
\begin{document}
\noindent
\lab{3}{LAB3 }

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Objective}
\begin{description}
  \item[$\cdot$ At the end of this lab you will:] 
  \item[\qquad $\bullet$ Add Shift operations and Branch operations to your ALU]
  \item[\qquad $\bullet$ Create a memory of 4 word deep, 9 bit wide to hold data]
  \item[\qquad $\bullet$ Learn about sequential logic]
  \item[\qquad $\bullet$ Assemble the complete Datapath ]
  \item[\qquad $\bullet$ Familiarize yourself with Xilinx device xc7z020clg484-1]
\end{description}
```

Here is a snippet of the pdf I get:
[image: Here is a snippet of the pdf I get:]

Thanks!

Comment: Eeekkk! There are better ways to do what you want. Help is on the way.

Comment: The optional argument of `\item` is not meant to contain the text of the entry, but should rather be used to change locally the mark.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't add the formatting of each item in a list manually; let the list formatting take care of itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Objective}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\cdot$,nosep]
  \item At the end of this lab you will:
  \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet,nosep]
    \item Add Shift operations and Branch operations to your ALU
    \item Create a memory of 4 word deep, 9 bit wide to hold data
    \item Learn about sequential logic
    \item Assemble the complete Datapath
    \item Familiarize yourself with Xilinx device xc7z020clg484-1
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Above I've used [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to set the `label` of each item at that specific level. Level 1 has a label set to `$\cdot$`, while level 2 has it set to `\textbullet`. This can be adjusted/set globally, but for the sake of the example I've kept it local.

Gaps between each item is suppressed (or at least condensed) to the maximum by using the `nosep` list option. `noitemsep` will provide some separation (space) between lists, but not space between items in the same list.

Many other adjustments are also possible (like margins/indentation), but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: `noitemsep` is the key that sets zero separation between items, `nosep` also sets zero space above and below the list.

Comment: @Manuel: Correct. I gather the OP is interested in removing most of the vertical spacing and used `nosep`. Mentioned it in the post for completeness.